# Reading JSON thru web service into POJOs annotated for Hibernate

Tags: json, hibernate, pojo, restlet-2.0

I am reading the following json through a web service. Is there a way to read the json into three appropriate POJOs? The POJOs are generated by hibernate and are used to communicate to the database.

Basically I need to read the `person` json into a `Perso`n POJO, the `pets` json into a set of `Pet` POJOs, and the `toy` json into a set of `Toy` POJOs.

The JSON

```
{
"person":{"first_name":"John", "last_name":"Smith"},
"pets":[{"species":"dog", "name":"Adama"}, {"species":"cat", "name":"Benton"} ],
"toys":[{"car":"corvet", "color":"black"}, {"action_figure":"hancock", "height":"1ft"} ]
}
```

The Web Service

```
@Post
public Representation readForm(Representation representation) {
    try {
        Person aPerson = …
        Set<Pet>  petSet = …
        Set<Toy> toySet = ...

      ….
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xStream . You will have to create a VO having all 3 types of your objects as properties. Give them respective aliases and you will get all 3 types of objects in that VO. You can get them simply by calling their getters.